# How to switch Input Method in Win32 Application Debug Console

Tags: winapi, win32-process

I have a Win32 gui app and create a console to debug my program
when i switch to console, i want to change my input mode to Alphanumeric input mode automatic

i create my console use AllocConsole in other thread and handle ctrl message

```
//key code == ctrl + tab
HIMC h_imc = ImmGetContext()
if(!h_imc){
   DWORD err_code = GetLastError() // err_code = 0
}
// do set immstatus but h_imc is NULL
...
```

i try it with ImmGetContext to get my imm and check is already in alphanumeric input mode,but when i call ImmGetContext,it return null

i confuse why it is,and how can i do to make it work?

Comment: [`ImmGetContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/imm/nf-imm-immgetcontext) has an `HWND` argument, but you aren't providing one. The code either doesn't compile, or you have a custom implementation for `ImmGetContext` we cannot see. Please show a [mcve].

Comment: ohhh sorry i miss copy this.....in fact i set the  hwnd in this, the code can run